# Why does this state machine not maintain its state?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip, xc8

Hey there StackOverflow!

In the following code I have a simple state machine that changes the operation of some external lighting device (as the comments imply). The state is changed via the pressing of the button connected to GP1. The circuit connected to GP1 is a comparator debouncing circuit that compares VDD to 0.6VDD (I've also tried an RC/diode/schmitt trigger circuit), which then forces the signal LO. On a scope, we see a clean square wave when the button is actuated rapidly.

The **current (and *undesirable*)** behavior of the **PIC10F200** is as follows:

1. Switch is pressed (state = 0)
2. State machine variable increments (state = 1)
3. Lighting goes to case 1, and turns on
4. Lighting remains on for at least a second
5. Lighting turns off
6. System remains in this state until button is actuated again or
   powered off

**The question is: Why does it behave like this?** And how if possible, do I fix it such that a single press of the button equates to a single state increment, which the PIC then maintains for as long as the system is powered and the button is not actuated again?

```
#define SYS_FREQ        8000000L
#define FCY             SYS_FREQ/4
#define _XTAL_FREQ      4000000

/******************************************************************************/
/* User Global Variable Declaration                                           */
/******************************************************************************/


/******************************************************************************/
/* Main Program                                                               */
/******************************************************************************/

__CONFIG(MCLRE_ON & CP_OFF & OSC_IntRC);

void main(void)
{
    TRIS = 0b111110;

    unsigned char state = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0: // IDLE/OFF
                if (GPIObits.GP0) GPIObits.GP0 = 0;
                break;
            case 1: // ON
                if (!GPIObits.GP0) GPIObits.GP0 = 1;
                break;
            case 2: // BLINK (slow)
                GPIObits.GP0 = !GPIObits.GP0;
                __delay_ms(100);
                break;
            case 3: // BLINK (fast)
                GPIObits.GP0 = !GPIObits.GP0;
                __delay_ms(50);
                break;
            case 4: // BEAT DETECT
                GPIObits.GP0 = GPIObits.GP2;
                break;
            default:
                state = 0;
                break;
        }

        if (!GPIObits.GP1)
        {
            __delay_ms(250);
            state++;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: Since there seems to be a little confusion as to what I am trying to accomplish with this code/system, lets provide the full context. This microcontroller, the **PIC10F200** is part of an overall board design for an electroluminescent (EL) wire driver. The miconcontroller **simply controls whether or not the driver circuit is enabled** by connecting `GP0` to the `EN` port of the driver IC. **The system has four modes of operation**, the wire is constantly on, the wire is blinking, the wire is blinking faster, and the wire blinks whenever a low-frequency beat is detected (another circuit in the system). **The transition from these modes of operation is governed by a pushbutton (on momentarily) switch to be mounted on the PCB.** This necessitates that `state` in the code above remains stable between button actuations. It currently does not do this and behaves as described in the original part of this post. As the question title states, **why isn't `state` stable currently, and how do I make it so?**

**UPDATE (2014-03-08): Solution**

The following settings need to be set assuming GP0 is the output, GP2 is your T0CKI and you have a switch that drives the signal to LO when actuated.

```
TRIS = 0b111110;
OPTION = 0b11101111;
```

Whether or not bits 0-3 for OPTION really matter is a judgement call and whether or not you choose to use the WDT module.

Additionally, the implementation for the button release detection is a simple counter mechanism that resets upon GP2 being LO at any point during the count.

```
if (TMR0 > 0)
{
    while (count < 20)
    {
        if (!GPIObits.GP2) count = 0;
        __delay_ms(10);
        count++;
    }
    TMR0 = 0;
    state++;
}
```

Comment: So gp1 is the button, gp0 the led and gp2 is what? Also, how the button works? One click(press and release) gives 1 and another one 0?

Comment: Yes, GP1 is connected to the button, GP0 the LED/EL wire driver EN port (eventually), GP2 is the input from a low-frequency detection circuit (bass from... loud music), which isn't connected yet since I can't even get the state machine to work properly. The button is an on-momentarily button, like the really basic kind you find in most cheap electronics. So when its depressed the contacts are connected and VDD goes through to the comparator circuit (LM324N op-amp).

Comment: why are you trying to do it with "states". The thing you are trying to achieve is easy. You dont need to complicate the code.

Comment: With `state`, I am trying to simply toggle between modes of operation for the device which are labelled in the code. With my current knowledge of the PIC, how XC8 works, and C, this is the simplest way I could come up with to accomplish this task. I am totally willing to try different approaches, with the exception of any solution in assembly, because not only does changing the language not address the problem, it introduces unnecessary implementation and support complexity.

Comment: What you describe is **one** state. When the button is pressed. In the future you may want to add something else but as it is right now it is one state. `if (!GPIObits.GP1){GPIObits.GP0 = 1; __delay_ms(1000); GPIObits.GP0 = 0;}`

Comment: What I have described in the question and in the comments is how the system **currently** behaves. My issue is that this is undesirable. The system should behave as the code reads: START -> IDLE -> switch actuation -> ON -> switch -> slower flashing -> switch -> faster flashing -> switch -> bass detection circuit (GP2) -> switch -> IDLE. I have referred to this sequencing of events in the context of the entire system as a simple state machine for simplicity sake, I know it is not the most complex usage of a state machine, but it is one that represents the system I am trying to construct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a hardware/software design problem!

1. When your program is in delay loop than your key button is not
   checked!
2. You are checking only on key press event, but you must also on key
   relase.

My purpose is that you can use GP2 (T0CKI) pin instead GP1 for key buttom. This pin has schmitt trigger input if is used as counter TMR0 input. After that configure your MCPU TMR0 as counter with external clock on GP2 (T0CKI) pin. You must also set the T0SE bit to configure counter that will increment on high-to-low transition on the T0CKI pin.
In program after any loop check the TMR0 content if biger than 0 the key was pressed.
Wait some ms and check if key was relased if relased than increase the `state` variable and clear TMR0 content.

Comment: You are completely right on your first point(+1). My code takes care only the second one. If the led has a long interval then you have a magor problem. Your solution is interesting but anorthodox. The way you deal these kind of problems is to use a timer. Check the timer(case 2 and 3 without the delays), if time expires then led(on or off) and reset the timer.

Comment: Thanx! Actualy I'm talking about timer `TMR0` configured as counter triggered via pin GP2 (T0CKI), so you must press button 256 times to turn counter to 0. But also your way is possible!

Comment: @GJ : So `OPTION = 0b11111111;` right now, according to the documentation, `T0CS` is correct for using `GP2/T0CKI`, `T0SE` is XOR'd with `GP2` to produce the input to the MUX. So for a HI -> LO transition, its appropriate for `T0SE` to be 1 and for `GP2` to hit HI to feed the MUX LO. Are the prescaler settings relevant here?

Comment: @James Lui: You can also include the prascaler unit if you clear the `PSA` bit in `option` register but there is no need! Use the `pracaler` assigned to the `WDT` in that case you can use the WDT for longer time intervals when you are waiting in delay loop.

Comment: Ooooh, we're very close now. I've set `OPTION = 0b1110111;` which seems to produce stable state changes, however if I actuate the button too much, the program hangs. Since its a simple program there are two possibilities. 1) Its hanging inside the portion of the code I use to check that `GP2` is HI consistently before resetting `TMR0` and incrementing the state. or 2) I have inadvertently halted state transitions and the program is stuck at `IDLE` which is unlikely. @GJ and @valter : our dialectic here and both of your suggestions have cumulatively brought us here, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
__delay_ms(250); <-- too small delay
```

While you are pressing the button slowly, the loop may rotate several times. Try increasing it to 1000ms.

**Update**

You should run the PIC with WDT (watch dog timer) disabled, otherwise it will reset the pic in few seconds. That is similar to your observation. You can blink a LED at the beginning of main function to check if this happen or you can initialization `unsigned char state = 1;` and see the behavior then.

Try this  `__CONFIG(MCLRE_ON & CP_OFF & OSC_IntRC & WDT_OFF);`

Comment: I tried this earlier, the system still behaves the same way, even if I set it to something arbitrarily huge like... 10000ms, still the same way, it lights up, it lasts for a second, and then it turns off and stays that way...

Comment: I suspect if the pic get reset when it lights up. How do you power the light. Does the light draw much power or introduce any glitches or interference or is there any relays? Are you using good PSU for pic?

Comment: Well for testing, I'm using an LED... which should draw very... very... little current. The circuit that the output will eventually enable will draw even less. The PSU is basically USB (5V, 500mA).

Comment: Have you connected pull up resistor for GP1 to stop it floating? Try directly connecting button to GP1 skipping comparator debouncing circuit. No debouncing is required here as you are using a delay of 250ms.

Comment: I guess your comparator output is active low. Did you check that?

Comment: The PIC10F200 is the lowest end PIC available from Microchip, it does not have a comparator module (which actually would've been useful for debouncing =()...

If you're referring to the analog comparator I constructed outside the PIC, yes, when V+ > V-, Vout drops to 0, which indicates the button is depressed... but I am checking for !GPIObits.GP1, so that shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: Well, the debouncing circuit was only thought of because the input from the button was noisy to the point where 250ms actually wasn't enough of a delay, connecting the button directly however changes nothing about how the system behaves, thanks for making all these suggestions btw, I haven't tried them, I'm sure it's just some random detail about how the PIC10F works that I'm not getting...

Comment: For LM324 when V+ > V-, Vout goes to **VDD**. Your state machine is waiting for a LOW that's why !GP1 is used.

Comment: Are you sure GP1 goes LOW when button is **pressed**?

Comment: Yup, definitely does on scope, with an LED (on to off) and clearly through GP1 as the state changes, it's just what happens afterwards that is the issue at hand.

Comment: 1. Is watch dog timer disabled ? 2. Keep the scope connected to GP1 to see if there are any glitches coming when the malfunctioning happens.

Comment: Watchdog timer, I don't know, the compiler isn't recognizing the WDT_OFF macro in the __CONFIG() function. Which is worrying to say the least, is there a CONFIG reg that I could set directly?

Comment: After some quick Googling, `WDT_OFF` macro is now **`WDTE_OFF`** to match the register name in the documentation.

Comment: It is not, I am currently exploring GJs TMR0 solution to see if that can address the instability of the input from the button. So far, I haven't been even able to get the button to light up...

Comment: Are you sure the pic does not get reset in any means? I would like if you blink an LED when the pic starts. If it gets reset time to time, the behavior is somewhat explainable.

Comment: Have you pulled up MCLR pin properly?

Comment: The programmer is attached to the board currently, which stipulates in the documentation to pull up the MCLR pin, this has been done. I tested the reset case by rewriting the code to turn on the LED on permanently and another scenario where the LED is directly linked to the input. The PIC never reset in either of those scenarios, also I hooked up a scope to all the pins to monitor the status of the device. Never saw the MCLR line change besides when the programmer asserted it.

Comment: Now the problem narrows down that scope can't see a GP1 change but program detects a GP1 going low! How about using another pic chip.

Comment: This is my third chip. I have a tube of 10... But you can see my frustration with this issue now right? I literally have no idea why the PIC is behaving the way it is and there is no documentation of any kind from anyone seeing similar issues. So either nobody has ever tried to use the PIC10F200 for this purpose, or nobody ever ran into this issue, or I'm doing something really really wrong. I'm hoping it's the last one, because then there is at least hope for a solution. I'll update this thread when I try GJ's latest suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

move your

```
if (!GPIObits.GP1){
    if(isPressed == false){
        //__delay_ms(250); //you dont need the delay
        state++;
        if(state == 5){state = 0;}
        isPressed = true;
    }
}
else{isPressed = false;}
```

before the `switch` statement. `char isPressed = false;` before the `while` loop

valter

Comment: There is no need to use an extra variable `isPressed` my solution is quite good, and if `state` bigger than 4 the default case sentence should set it to 0.

Comment: @GJ. *should set it to 0* and if the button is pressed it will make it to one. So you loose the zero state. Another thing, in microcontrolers you dont use delays of 250 msec to check if a button is pressed. You have `schmitt trigger` to take care of that.

Comment: No you will not loose the 0 state. When variable `state` increase up 5 then default case sentence should set it to 0 and affter that the next loop should set the GP0 to 0 and switch off the LED.

Comment: @GJ. You didnt understand my point. Lets say the button is pressed(GPIObits.GP1 = 0) and `state = 5`. The switch goes to default and sets `state = 0` and then the `if statement` is **true** and increases state to 1. The next iteration wont go to 0 but to 1. Also it is not `|` but `||`.

Comment: There is no need to go to 0 because this should switch off the GP0 and LED, but the next loop will set it to 1 again. Thanx for wrong or oparator!

Comment: @GJ. You are missing the point here. The point is your code has a problem in this particular senario and not if that problem is not visible. If he decides later to insert a delay in state zero, what happens? Anyway, if you read his latest comment(in the original post), he wants to change states every time the button is pressed and your code does not do that.

Comment: @valter : However, your solution is more or less what is already in the code, since the default clause with set `state` back to 0 anyways. I have tried this solution before to capture the "pressed" state and try to hold it such that the system doesn't believe the button has been pressed, but the system still behaves like I've described in the OP. @GJ : I am not trying to scroll through all the states at once, I want to get to state = 1, stay there until I actuate the switch again, in your code `state != 0` will basically be true for every state but 0, which means no state is ever stable.

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm again but with more details in your main post?

Comment: @JamesLui No. The code i posted has two major differences 1. what happens if GPIObits.GP1 remains to 0 longer than 250msec? It will change state which is a false flag (i corrected it) 2. What i was talking with `gj`(i placed the if statement before the switch one). If you still thing that my code is the same as yours feel free and use yours.

Comment: @valter : I am not trying to contradict you here, I am just saying that I have tried your code that I have written before when I was brainstorming ideas to solve this problem. And now, I am copying your code verbatim and placing it where you told me to, above the switch statement, and the resulting behavior of the system is the same. Hence, we need to an alternative solution.

Comment: @JamesLui The code works as it should. The problem is in your circuit connecting the button to gp1. It doesnt provide a clean palse. Thats why you should use a `schmitt trigger`. I have done that a million times